# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I get data from database:

```
$user = DB::table('view_users')->where([
                            'id'        => $friend->user_id,
                            'type'      => $friend->user_type,
                            'del_flg'   => 0,
                            'status'    => 1
            ])->first();
$username = $user->username;
```

but i have a error:

```
Trying to get property 'username' of non-object
```

When I use `dd($user->username)`, It still have result as string.
After I use `var_dump($user);exit;` to check type of varible `$user`, the result is a object.

Can you help me find the problem? Thank you very much

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ but he said `dd($user->username)` still have result as string

Comment: I think after you add `dd($user->username)`, there are still some codes make the $user empty. So please post the complete error message to get the error line.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved. May be $user is empty after I dd($user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if user has value.

```
if ($user) {
 $username = $user->username;
} else {
 // add your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have solved. May be $user is empty after I dd($user)

Answer (score 0):

I think , there is some promblems in your where clause
change like this ,

```
$user = DB::table('view_users')->where([
                                        ['id','=', $friend->user_id],
                                       ['type','=' $friend->user_type],
                                       ['del_flg','=', 0],
                                       ['status','=', 1]
                                   ])->first();
```